# How to get mathematica to simplify a result

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following output $\text{Li}_2\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)-4 \text{Li}_2\left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right)$.

This turns out to be equivalent to $\displaystyle\log^2(1+\sqrt{2})-\frac{\pi^2}{4}$.

How can I get mathematica to simplify the first result to the second? I have other (more complicated) results like this that I need to simplify. `FullSimplify` and `Simplify` don't do anything, it just throws the same thing that I put in back at me...

```
FullSimplify[PolyLog[2, 3 - 2 Sqrt[2]] - 4 PolyLog[2, -1 + Sqrt[2]]]

Log[1+2^(1/2)]^2-Pi^2/4
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think you have inputted it wrong. Li_2 means the function polylog_2

Comment: Okay.  Please include *Mathematica* code also for your "equivalent" expression so that there is no more miscommunication.

Comment: In version 7 `FullSimplify[PolyLog[2, 3 - 2 Sqrt[2]] - 4 PolyLog[2, -1 + Sqrt[2]]]` outputs `-(Pi^2/4) + Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]^2`, which is I believe what you want.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm using version 9.0.0.0. It doesn't work for me for some reason http://quickpic.info/z/1h.jpg

Comment: FYI: I wasn't doubting your veracity, rather such things often need to be localized to which versions they affect to best address them.  Thanks.

Comment: Version 8.0.0 doesn't simplify that expression either.

Comment: Just tried, and for me version 7 doesn't do it either, so it doesn't seem a version problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Do you possibly have packages autoloaded which might affect this?

Comment: @celtschk For some reason I never saw your comment.  Trying the code again it *did not* simplify as I stated previously.  I don't know if one of the results was an error on my part, or if in fact something I had loaded affected this.  I shall endeavor to find out.